# Write a file in the middle of a shell script

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a simple shell script in my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system, and somewhere in the middle, I would like to write a file with some instructions. I was able to achieve this using echo but the text is indented

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *x*x*
    do
        dir=${file%}
        dir=${dir%.*}
        mkdir -p "./$dir" &&
        mv -n "$file" "./$dir"
        echo "
            #!/bin/bash
            #SBATCH -o %j.o
            #SBATCH -e %j.e
            #SBATCH -t 01-00:00:00
            mpirun -n 24 castep.mpi $dir " > sub.sh
        mv -n sub.sh "./$dir"
done
```

I've tried also cat like this

```
 cat > sub.sh << EOF
   #!/bin/bash
   #SBATCH -o %j.o
   #SBATCH -e %j.e
   #SBATCH -t 01-00:00:00
   mpirun -n 24 castep.mpi $dir " > sub.sh
 EOF
```

but it gives the following error

```
 line 17: warning: here-document at line 9 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
```

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I've added that. I'm on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS

Comment: I see 2 issues: (1) you forgot to remove the closing quote left over from the original `echo` version and (2) the closing EOF **must** be at the start of the line (not indented by one space, as it appears to be in your code). (You can indent it by a tab character **if** you change the `<<` to `<<-`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want lines to be indented in the generating script (for readability) but **not** indented in the generated `sub.sh` script, then you can do so with a here-document as follows:

1. change the `<<` to `<<-`
2. indent with TAB characters **not** spaces

The terminating EOF may also be indented with a TAB if you prefer. From `man bash`:

> ```
>    If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters are
>    stripped  from  input  lines  and  the line containing delimiter.  This
>    allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a  natural
>    fashion.
> ```

So

```
cat > sub.sh <<- EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    #SBATCH -o %j.o
    #SBATCH -e %j.e
    #SBATCH -t 01-00:00:00
    mpirun -n 24 castep.mpi "$dir" > sub.sh
EOF

^^^^ these are tabs not spaces
```

(I also removed the unbalanced double quote - presumably left over from the original `echo` version - and instead double-quoted the `$dir` variable to prevent possible word-splitting.)

Comment: This work. Apparently the problem was me using MS VS Code for some reason it was making my tabs into space. When I did it in vim worked well

Answer (score 0):

You could try the next:

```
    echo -e '
        #!/bin/bash
        #SBATCH -o %j.o
        #SBATCH -e %j.e
        #SBATCH -t 01-00:00:00
        mpirun -n 24 castep.mpi $dir " > sub.sh
    #mv -n sub.sh "./$dir' | tr -s "  "
```

I've replaced double quotes by single quotes and added `tr -s "  "` which should remove indentation.